# Ngrok (app.) Subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, ngrok

I'm using ngrok for development.

So, I have a Node/Express application that uses different subdomains like `app.`, `api.`, etc.

My question: is there way to use `app.` & `api.` subdomains in ngrok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ngrok binds your port and provides you a url that you can connect to from outside your local system. So if you start your sub domains on different ports and then ngrok those ports, it will work.